# Не отображается изображение в ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

Не отображается изображение в ListView, в ячейки где должно быть изображение пишет System.Drawing.Bitmap

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Logo", 120);
listView1.Columns.Add("Название", 120);

for (int i = 0; Total_count > i; i++)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(icon_url.ToString());
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
    myResponse.Close();

    ListViewItem newitem = new ListViewItem(Convert.ToString(bmp));
    newitem.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToString(games.games[i].Name));
    listView1.Items.Add(newitem);
}
```

Comment: Интересно, а какого эффекта вы ждете, когда пишете это: `Convert.ToString(bmp)`?

Comment: если вам подошло решение - отметьте его галочкой

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно создать `ImageList`:

```
ImageList il = new ImageList();
```

и установить его как источник картинок в вашем `ListView`:

```
listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
listView1.LargeImageList = il;
```

Затем в цикле вы добавляете картинки в эту коллекцию:

```
il.Images.Add(bmp);
```

и в `ListViewItem` указываете индекс нужной картинки:

```
newitem.ImageIndex = i;
```

<sub>PS: код не проверял, основано на [этом ответе en.SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255732/6766879)</sub>